# What's the relation between GetHashCode and Equals in a IEqualityComparer implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

I have a class A that inherits from a class B and implements `IEqualityComparer<A>`.
This means class A provides its own implementation of both Equals and GetHashCode methods. So far so good.
The problem is that I don't understand why the code behaves in the following way:

debugger will only reach A's Equals implementation breakpoint if A's GetHashCode implementation returns 
`this.GetHashCode()` instead of
`obj.GetHashCode()`, with "obj" being the parameter that GetHashCode's signature defines(a variable of type A, in my case).

Intuitively, I thought that I should return the hashcode of the object I received, but doing so makes the compiler ignore the instance's Equals implementation.

Why does this happen?

Code demonstration:

```
public class A : B, IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        //my implementation...
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A obj)
    {
        //return obj.GetHashCode(); -> this makes my Equals implementation above be ignored! Why?
        return this.GetHashCode(); -> my Equals implementation is used
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code explaining the problem, it is hard to guess it right

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` doesn't `override` the base implementation of `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` allows you to supply an instance of the implementor as an equality comparer for `T`. This is a common parameter to several linq extensions and generic collection constructors.

Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` effects the way instances of a class are tested for equality. Tapping into other implmentations that call `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, like the base `=` and `!=` operators and linq extensions and generic collection constructors where you don't supply an alternative `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

These concepts are similar but **serve different purposes, they are not partially interchangable**.

---

Let me expand with an example,

```
public class A
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = (hash * 23) + 
                StringComparer.Ordinal.GetHashCode(this.Value1);
            hash = (hash * 23) + this.Value2;
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var a = obj as A;
        if (a == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (a.Value2 != this.Value2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(
            a.Value1,
            this.Value1);
    }
}
```

This implementation of `A` correctly overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, this change is sufficient to ensure that after calling the linq extension

```
var distinct = aSequneceOfA.Distinct();
```

`distinct` will not contain any instances that have both the same `Value2` and ordinally comparable `Value1`. No other interface implementation is necessary to achieve this.

---

Now, suppose that in some situation I wasn't happy with this ordinal comparison for `Value1`, perhaps I require some case insensitivity. I might implement an new equality comparer.

```
public class AComparerInsensitive : IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            return y == null;
        }

        if (y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (x.Value2 != y.Value2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(
            x.Value1,
            y.Value1)
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A a)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = (hash * 23) + 
                StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(
                    a.Value1);
            hash = (hash * 23) + a.Value2;
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow me to call the alternative overload of `Distinct`,

```
var insensitivelyDistinct = aSequneceOfA.Distinct(
    new AComparerInsensitive());
```

This overload of distinct ingnores `A`s overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and uses `AComparerInsensitive` to perform the comparison.

Comment: @Veverke I hope my expanded answer makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using the wrong interface. `IEqualityComparer<>` is typically used for a class that compares instances of ***other*** types.

Your type should simply implement `IEquatable<A>` **and** override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`. Note the signatures.

Like this:

```
public class A : B, IEquatable<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A other)
    {
       if (other == null || GetType() != other.GetType())
           return false;

       //your implementation
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as A);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //your implementation
    }
}
```

Then you can do stuff like `someEnumerableOfA.Distinct()` and the Linq method will use your implementation.

The other option is to do:

```
public class A : B // no interfaces
{
}

public class AEqualComparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
       //your implementation
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A x)
    {
        //your implementation
    }
}
```

With this other option you need `someEnumerableOfA.Distinct(new AEqualComparer ())`.

Comment: The reason I chose IEqualityComparer is because my solution relies in calling IEnumerable<>.Distinct<>(IEqualityComparer<>). In other words, if I want to return the distinct elements of my collection, why can I not use Distinct here and thus be required to provide a IEqualityComparer implementation?

Comment: OP implements right interface but in wrong way. For more info refer the linked duplicate thread.

Comment: @Veverke, if you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, you won't need to implement or supply `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Disagree. You shouldn't have a class `A` implement `IEqualityComparer<A>`. That is misuse. Look at `String` class. It implements `IEquatable<String>`. However, there are other classes, like `StringComparer` which implement `IEqualityComparer<String>` (but **not** `IEqualityComparer<StringComparer>`).

Comment: @Jodrell: And how will my IEnumerable call to Distinct be ? variable.Distinct(this) - where the current class overrides Equals and GetHashCode?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I know that; you're right on the money, that is misusing the interface, but that **should not** cause any problem, since signature is different. as you said there should be a comparer class dedicated doing just comparison.

Comment: @Jodrell: remark: doing so has the "downside" of having to cast "object" into my own type...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Exactly. It is like if I make a class `Car`, I may or may not choose to make a `Car` "intrinsically" equality-comparable to other `Car`s, for example checking if the registration plate numbers agree. But then I could make another `class ByColorCarEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>` or `class ByBrandAndModelIDCarEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>`. But to make a "car" whose purpose it is to compare "cars" by some criteria, is confusing. Cars are for driving in. They are something else than car comparers.

Comment: Again, I agree with you completely. My point is there is nothing wrong technically but it is a wrong design which makes confusion etc but.. It will work is what I say, and the suggested duplicate says why it doesn't work.